# Yii2 - Posted form value evaluates to null

Tags: php, yii2

I am working with an advanced template install of Yii2. I am not going to use the supplied signup feature to add new users. Instead, new users will be added by admin users. As such, I have rewritten the `actionCreate` function to populate the needed fields such as passwordhash, verification token, etc. What's left for form input are three fields: `Username, Email and Role`. Username and email are text fields and the Role input is a dropdown list populated with Role values. When I submit, the insert fails. The error reporting shows that every field except the Username and Email are correct. It shows the Username and Email have been set to null. The Role value from the same form is correct. The error reporting also shows that the `POST` holds all three fields correctly. In my `actionCreate` function I set the `Yii::$app->request` to a variable `$req`. I then set each of the three fields to their corresponding model properties. For example, `$model->username = $req->post('username')`. I do this for Username, Email and Role. Role is set correctly while Username and Email become null. In the documentation of the Request object it notes that an assignment like I'm using `($model->property = $req->post('field') )` is in effect checking to see if the field `isset()` and if it is not, return `NULL`. I have tried setting Username and Email to "safe" and even removed all validation, nothing works. If I hard code the Username and Email in the `actionCreate` function, everything works. Any ideas?
My Form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
   
   <?php echo $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(); ?>
       
   <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(); ?>
       
   <?php echo $form->field($model, 'role_id')->dropDownList($model->getRoleList()); ?>

   <div class="form-group">
       <?php echo Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
   </div>

  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My actionCreate function:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();
        $req = Yii::$app->request;
        if ($req->isPost) {
            $model->username = $req->post('username');
            $model->email = $req->post('email');
            $model->role_id = $req->post('role_id');
            $model->generateAuthKey();
            $model->generateEmailVerificationToken();
            $model->setPassword('Lookout!');
            if ($model->save()) {
                //$this->sendEmail($model);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New user'. $model->username .' created.');
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }  
        }
        
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Any input (no pun intended) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add ```false``` inside your ```$model->save()```,  use it as ```$model->save(false)```.

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar using `false` as `save()` param only skips validation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ramisha, but adding false to the save did not work.

However, instead of using the Yii::$app->request I went straight to the $_POST object. I tested if the $_POST['User'] was set and then assigned it to the $model->attributes. This worked although it doesn't really solve the mystery.

```
if(isset($_POST['User'])){
                $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            }
```

Comment: Please add the js code if any in your form file and the model code in your question. Have you tried dumping the ```$_POST``` in your controller if it is having the values in username and email fields?

Answer (score 0):

**You must use the method** [**load()**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#load()-detail)

```
# code...
if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { //$model->load($_POST)
   //$this->sendEmail($model);
   # code...
```

> **Populates the model with input data**.
>
> This method provides a convenient shortcut for:

```
if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
    if ($model->save()) {
        // handle success
    }
}
```

**Good luck.**

Answer (score 0):

If you use `yii\widgets\ActiveForm::field()`, `yii\helpers\Html::activeInput()` or related methods to generate input for model's attribute Yii will use [`yii\helpers\Html::getInputName()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-html#getInputName()-detail) to generate input's name. The generated name will look like this: `ModelName[attributeName]`.

So, for your form the post data looks like this:

```php
[
    'User' => [
        'username' => 'something',
        'email' => 'something@example.com'
        'role_id' => '123'
    ]
]
```

Because the form was generated for `User` model.

Using `$req->post('username')` actually tries to access `$_POST['username']` while you need to access `$_POST['User']['username'];`

To deal with it, you can do following:

```php
$req = Yii::$app->request;
if ($req->isPost) {
   $data = $req->post('User');
   $model->username = $data['username'];
   $model->email = $data['email'];
   $model->role_id = $data['role_id'];
   // ...

   // or you can set all safe attributes at once:
   $model->attributes = $req->post('User');
}
```

Or you can let `Model::load()` method do the work for you. It will automatically use model's name to access data in array:

```php
$req = Yii::$app->request;
if ($model->load($req->post()) {
    $model->generateAuthKey();
    $model->generateEmailVerificationToken();
    // ...
}
```

`Model::load()` method will only load data to attributes that are considered "safe". Those are attributes where at least one validation rule is defined.

Of course you can access `$_POST['User']` directly without going through `yii\web\Request::post()` method.